# ServiceNow Stack Overflow Error

Tags: javascript, stack-overflow, onchange, servicenow

I am using an `onChange()` Client Script in Service Now to round the entry of a field to the next highest, even, hundredth upon entry of data into the field. I am running into a stack overflow message,

```
onChange script error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded function (){var o=i(m,arguments);return l.apply(n,o)}
```

In the API is suggests checking the `oldValue` against the `newValue` to make sure to unnecessarily run the `onChange()`.  This is what I have, and I can't seem to work it out. Your help is appreciated.

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) {
if (newValue === oldValue){
    return;
}else if (isLoading || newValue === '') {
    return;
}else{
    if (newValue) {
        if (newValue != oldValue){

            var round = ((Math.ceil(newValue * 100) /100);
            g_form.setValue('nitrate_0_50', round);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The script is unnecessary complex, but I don't see a reason for a stack overflow. What is the context of the script?

Comment: Bear with me, I'm very new to this.  I am entering a test result into a field named "Nitrate".  I then run a script include that takes the entered value and, with the use of Ajax, pulls a corresponding value from a different table.

Example  -  Enter 4 into "Nitrate" and the field "Nitrate Result" will update a corresponding parts-per million concentration in a saltwater fish tank.

The issue is the data table only includes even valued measurements and is measured in a range of 0 to 1 ml in .xx increments.

Comment: That makes little sense. Please update the question with a proper description of the context. Leave out unimportant stuff like AJAX requests etc.

Comment: Are you familiar with ServiceNow?  This code executes with an onChange() function. So when you change the data in a field, it notes the oldValue and and allows you to do something with the newValue automatically within that function. If you're not familiar with ServiceNow I'm not sure how much help you can offer.

Comment: Is the extra open paren in "var round = ((Math.ceil(newValue * 100) /100);" a typo in the question or is it actually in the script? I expect that would actually generate a syntax error, but want to be sure...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just as you explain in the comments.
You have a field. When changing this field you call your `onChange` function. This in turn does som calculation and changes the value of the field. And this leads to a new onChange event.

You should there fore not write to the field again in your `onChange` function.